# Airport Lounge in OR Tambo International Airport, Johannesburg

Tags: air-travel, transit, lounges

I am shortly flying from London Heathrow to Windhoek, Namibia with a 5 hour wait in OR Tambo International Airport, Johannesburg.   I fly into Terminal A and out of Terminal B at OR Tambo International.

I am flying BA for both legs of the journey, on a single booking.

I have booked time in the Mashonzha Lounge which I believe is airside in the departure area of Terminal A.

Will I be able to reach the Mashonzha Lounge in the departure area of Terminal A, if I am flying out of Terminal B, or do I need to change the lounge booking to a Terminal B lounge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airside, Johannesburg OR Tambo airport only has a single terminal, so you will have no trouble accessing the lounge.

The Terminal A/Terminal B distinction relates to the location of the check-in counters for different airlines, which are split into two different areas which are then named Terminal A and terminal B. Both check-in areas then feed into the same terminal area.